# Android Activity: Listener for outside touch event

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-dialog, onactivityresult

I have an Activity shown as a Dialog:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);
    setFinishOnTouchOutside(true);
}
```

When the user closes the Activity-Dialog by touching outside the Activity-Dialog window, the Activity finishes.

How can I set a Listener on this event?

This is important because I want to be able to call

```
setResult(intResultCode, intent);
```

right before finishing.

Calling setResult() in onPause() can be too late already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why to struggle that much? just override finish() method in Avtivity...

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    setResult(int resultCode, Intent data);
    super.finish();
}
```

Comment: It is impossible to distinguish between the user touching the outside and finishing by calling finish in code.

Answer (score 0):

first put

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)
```

and after that use

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    Rect dialogBounds = new Rect();
    getWindow().getDecorView().getHitRect(dialogBounds);

    if (!dialogBounds.contains((int) ev.getX(), (int) ev.getY())) {
        // Tapped outside so we finish the activity
        this.finish();
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Comment: Did you actually read the question? I'm specifically asking for a Dialog Activity.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. You can override `onTouchEvent()`

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE == event.getAction()) {
        // Your logic
        // return true if you don't want to pass event further
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

If you don't get `ACTION_OUTSIDE` event, possibly you need to add `FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL` and `FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH` window flags. Works for me without it.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH);
    ...
}
```